# Using TortoiseGit, can I commit and svn dcommit in one step?

Tags: git, svn, commit, tortoisegit, dcommit

I am using TortoiseGit and am working with an svn repository using git-svn.

Sometimes I want to make a one line change and dcommit it to the svn repo immediately (so the CI server will pick up the change).

Currently I have to git commit, then dcommit. It's an extra step for something I want to do quickly...it would be nice if I could just commit and dcommit in one step. Alternatively, is there a command line command I could use to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svn commands from TortoiseGit are:

- only supported very recently ([June 2009, ticket 100](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=100&can=1&q=dcommit))
- have still some quirks to work out (August 2009, [ticket 131](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=131&can=1&q=dcommit))

So regarding the GUI, may be opening a new ticket would be a good idea.

As for the command-line, I do not think there is a native git command able to do that, which leaves a custom script to achieve that sequence (similar in principal to the one in this "[Showing commits not yet on master](http://randomcode.net.nz/2009/08/27/showing-commits-not-yet-on-master/)" article, at the end of it).

Comment: thanks - I just started really working with Git last month after discovering that TortoiseGit is fairly stable; I wasn't aware that git-svn support is so new.